# Subscrition Service with ical4j on GlassFish

Tags: java, calendar, glassfish, icalendar

this is my first question here and I hope to finde someone to answer it.

Situation now:

- GlassFish 4 Server
- ical4j for ICS generation
- Method to download an .ics manually availiable (variable timespan)
- there is only one calendar
- no changes allowed on calendar (only over frontend)

Target:

- offering a link to subscribe on the calendar

My idea would be making a RESTful resource which generates the calendar mentioned above when called. Could that work? Or do I have to go the hard way and set up a server that can provide URIs starting with `webcal://`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nobody answered my question, but I resolved my problem by the help of other posts on SO.

I had tried to set up a CalDAV server (DAViCal in this case). The server worked and I could also subscribe to the calenders created. But another problem was still there: There are users in my portal where the "actual" calander is presented over a portlet. There is only one calendar at the time, but (!) a user can filter this calendar for a subset of events he's interested in. This calander should be saved and automatically synced with the main calendar.

Creating this subset was easy, but I couldn't sync those resulting calendars with the CalDAV server because I haven't find a method to create a user! I've searched in various RFCs (WebDAV [RFC3744](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3744.html), it's extensions [RFC4791] and also CalDav [RFC2446](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2446.html)).

So I tried to just lookup the output the CalDAV server generated. It's pretty easy to understand with the help of the mentioned RFCs. So I setup a REST-Class and for testing purposes just build a calendar and returned it as a "text/calendar" (built with ical4j). Then I opend iCalendar and subscribed to my REST-Class and everything worked fine. The events were imported just as i wanted it.

This is my dummy class for testing. It's creating a calendar with 2015-12-23 as the "pre-christmas-day".

```
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import net.fortuna.ical4j.model.Calendar;
import net.fortuna.ical4j.model.Date;
import net.fortuna.ical4j.model.component.VEvent;
import net.fortuna.ical4j.model.property.CalScale;
import net.fortuna.ical4j.model.property.Name;
import net.fortuna.ical4j.model.property.Organizer;
import net.fortuna.ical4j.model.property.ProdId;
import net.fortuna.ical4j.model.property.Version;
import net.fortuna.ical4j.util.UidGenerator;

@Path("calendar")
public class CalendarRest {

    @GET
    @Path("test")
    @Produces("text/calendar")
    public Response getCalendarTest() {
        try {
            java.util.Calendar javaCalendar = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
            javaCalendar.set(java.util.Calendar.MONTH, java.util.Calendar.DECEMBER);
            javaCalendar.set(java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 23);

            Calendar calendar = new Calendar();
            calendar.getProperties().add(new ProdId("-//Ben Fortuna//iCal4j 1.0//EN"));
            calendar.getProperties().add(Version.VERSION_2_0);
            calendar.getProperties().add(CalScale.GREGORIAN);
            calendar.getProperties().add(new Name("Eventcalendar"));

            // VEVENT
            VEvent christmas = new VEvent(new Date(javaCalendar.getTime()), "Pre Christmas Day");
            christmas.getProperties().add(new Organizer("TestOrganizer"));
            // initialise as an all-day event..
            UidGenerator ug = new UidGenerator("1");
            christmas.getProperties().add(ug.generateUid());
            
            calendar.getComponents().add(christmas);

            return Response
                    .ok(calendar.toString())
                    .build();
        } catch (SocketException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(CalendarRest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(CalendarRest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return Response.serverError().build();
    }
}
```

This calss was my first try and immediatelly solved my problem! It's just for demonstrating purposes and not complete (see exceptions caught).

To get everything working you have to be conform with the RFC2446!

The dependency used (maven):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mnode.ical4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>ical4j</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.7</version>
</dependency>
```

I hope I could help those people having the same issue. If there are any questions just ask and I'll try to answer as soon as possible.